# node unable to run ember-cli on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

Hi I am not able to run ember on ubuntu 12.04
ember-cli 1.10
the reason i am using node 10.26 because it is last stable node.
for node v0.11.14 I am getting same error

```
rigel@rigel:/usr/local/bin$ ls
bash  bashbug  bower  buster  ember  grunt  parse #ember and bower red in color

echo $NODE_PATH
/home/rigel/.nvm/v0.10.26/lib/node_modules:/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript

rigel@rigel:~$ node -v
v0.10.26
rigel@rigel:~$ npm -v
1.4.3
rigel@rigel:~$ nvm current
v0.10.26
rigel@rigel:~$ ember --version
ember: command not found

rigel@rigel:~$ npm ls -g
```

.
.
.

├─┬ broccoli-es3-safe-recast@1.0.0
  │ └─┬ es3-safe-recast@1.0.0
  │   ├── es-simpler-traverser@0.0.1
  │   ├── esprima@1.1.0-dev-harmony (git+https://github.com/thomasboyt/esprima#4be906f1abcbb6822e33526b4bab725c6095afcd)
  │   └─┬ recast@0.5.27
  │     ├── ast-types@0.3.38
  │     ├── cls@0.1.5
  │     ├── esprima@1.1.0-dev-harmony (git+https://github.com/ariya/esprima.git#c8d226bf709353ccff9d9064fc3f864382ac9338)
  │     ├── private@0.1.5
  │     └─┬ source-map@0.1.32
  │       └── amdefine@0.1.0
  ├─┬ broccoli-es6-concatenator@0.1.8
  │ ├─┬ es6-module-transpiler@0.3.6
  │ │ └─┬ optimist@0.3.7
  │ │   └── wordwrap@0.0.2
  │ └── mkdirp@0.3.5
  ├── broccoli-file-mover@0.4.1
  ├── broccoli-file-remover@0.3.1
  ├─┬ broccoli-filter@0.1.7
  │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
  │ ├── promise-map-series@0.2.0
  │ ├─┬ quick-temp@0.1.0
  │ │ ├── mktemp@0.3.5
  │ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
  │ └── walk-sync@0.1.0
  ├─┬ broccoli-jshint@0.5.3
  │ ├─┬ chalk@0.4.0
  │ │ ├── ansi-styles@1.0.0
  │ │ ├── has-color@0.1.7
  │ │ └── strip-ansi@0.1.1
  │ ├─┬ findup-sync@0.1.3
  │ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11
  │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
  │ │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
  │ │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
  │ │ └── lodash@2.4.1
  │ ├─┬ jshint@2.5.6
  │ │ ├─┬ cli@0.6.4
  │ │ │ └─┬ glob@3.2.11
  │ │ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │ │ │   └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
  │ │ │     ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
  │ │ │     └── sigmund@1.0.0
  │ │ ├─┬ console-browserify@1.1.0
  │ │ │ └── date-now@0.1.4
  │ │ ├── exit@0.1.2
  │ │ ├─┬ htmlparser2@3.7.3
  │ │ │ ├── domelementtype@1.1.1
  │ │ │ ├── domhandler@2.2.0
  │ │ │ ├── domutils@1.5.0
  │ │ │ ├── entities@1.0.0
  │ │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13
  │ │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
  │ │ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │ │ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
  │ │ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.31
  │ │ ├── shelljs@0.3.0
  │ │ ├── strip-json-comments@1.0.1
  │ │ └── underscore@1.6.0
  │ └─┬ mkdirp@0.4.2
  │   └── minimist@0.0.8
  ├─┬ broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers@0.2.5
  │ └── mkdirp@0.3.5
  ├─┬ broccoli-merge-trees@0.2.0
  │ └── promise-map-series@0.2.0
  ├─┬ broccoli-sane-watcher@0.0.7
  │ ├── broccoli-slow-trees@1.0.0
  │ └─┬ sane@0.7.1
  │   ├─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
  │   │ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
  │   │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
  │   ├─┬ walker@1.0.6
  │   │ └─┬ makeerror@1.0.8
  │   │   └── tmpl@1.0.1
  │   └── watch@0.10.0
  ├── broccoli-static-compiler@0.2.0
  ├─┬ broccoli-uglify-js@0.1.3
  │ ├─┬ broccoli-filter@0.1.6
  │ │ ├─┬ broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers@0.2.0
  │ │ │ └─┬ glob@3.2.11
  │ │ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │ │ │   └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
  │ │ │     ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
  │ │ │     └── sigmund@1.0.0
  │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
  │ │ ├── promise-map-series@0.2.0
  │ │ ├─┬ quick-temp@0.1.0
  │ │ │ ├── mktemp@0.3.5
  │ │ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
  │ │ └── walk-sync@0.1.0
  │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.15
  │   ├── async@0.2.10
  │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
  │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
  │   ├─┬ source-map@0.1.34
  │   │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
  │   └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
  ├── broccoli-unwatched-tree@0.1.1
  ├─┬ broccoli-writer@0.1.1
  │ ├─┬ quick-temp@0.1.2
  │ │ ├── mktemp@0.3.5
  │ │ ├── rimraf@2.2.8
  │ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
  │ └── rsvp@3.0.14
  ├─┬ chalk@0.5.1
  │ ├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
  │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.2
  │ ├─┬ has-ansi@0.1.0
  │ │ └── ansi-regex@0.2.0
  │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@0.3.0
  │ │ └── ansi-regex@0.2.1
  │ └── supports-color@0.2.0
  ├─┬ concat-stream@1.4.6
  │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │ ├─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13
  │ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
  │ │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
  │ │ └── string_decoder@0.10.31
  │ └── typedarray@0.0.6
  ├─┬ configstore@0.3.1
  │ ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2
  │ ├─┬ js-yaml@3.0.2
  │ │ ├─┬ argparse@0.1.15
  │ │ │ ├── underscore@1.4.4
  │ │ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
  │ │ └── esprima@1.0.4
  │ ├── object-assign@0.3.1
  │ ├── osenv@0.1.0
  │ └── uuid@1.4.2
  ├── connect-livereload@0.4.0
  ├── core-object@0.0.2
  ├── diff@1.0.8
  ├─┬ express@4.9.5
  │ ├─┬ accepts@1.1.1
  │ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.0.2
  │ │ │ └── mime-db@1.1.0
  │ │ └── negotiator@0.4.8
  │ ├── cookie@0.1.2
  │ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
  │ ├─┬ debug@2.0.0
  │ │ └── ms@0.6.2
  │ ├── depd@0.4.5
  │ ├── escape-html@1.0.1
  │ ├─┬ etag@1.4.0
  │ │ └── crc@3.0.0
  │ ├── finalhandler@0.2.0
  │ ├── fresh@0.2.4
  │ ├── media-typer@0.3.0
  │ ├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
  │ ├── methods@1.1.0
  │ ├─┬ on-finished@2.1.0
  │ │ └── ee-first@1.0.5
  │ ├── parseurl@1.3.0
  │ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
  │ ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.0.3
  │ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0
  │ │ └── ipaddr.js@0.1.3
  │ ├── qs@2.2.4
  │ ├── range-parser@1.0.2
  │ ├─┬ send@0.9.3
  │ │ ├── destroy@1.0.3
  │ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
  │ │ └── ms@0.6.2
  │ ├── serve-static@1.6.3
  │ ├─┬ type-is@1.5.2
  │ │ └─┬ mime-types@2.0.2
  │ │   └── mime-db@1.1.0
  │ ├── utils-merge@1.0.0
  │ └── vary@1.0.0
  ├─┬ findup@0.1.5
  │ ├── colors@0.6.2
  │ └── commander@2.1.0
  ├─┬ fs-extra@0.12.0
  │ └── jsonfile@2.0.0
  ├── git-repo-info@1.0.2
  ├─┬ glob@4.0.6
  │ ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2
  │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │ └─┬ once@1.3.1
  │   └── wrappy@1.0.1
  ├── inflection@1.5.0
  ├─┬ inquirer@0.5.1
  │ ├── async@0.8.0
  │ ├─┬ chalk@0.4.0
  │ │ ├── ansi-styles@1.0.0
  │ │ ├── has-color@0.1.7
  │ │ └── strip-ansi@0.1.1
  │ ├─┬ cli-color@0.3.2
  │ │ ├── d@0.1.1
  │ │ ├─┬ es5-ext@0.10.4
  │ │ │ ├── es6-iterator@0.1.1
  │ │ │ └── es6-symbol@0.1.0
  │ │ ├─┬ memoizee@0.3.7
  │ │ │ ├── event-emitter@0.3.1
  │ │ │ ├── lru-queue@0.1.0
  │ │ │ └── next-tick@0.2.2
  │ │ └─┬ timers-ext@0.1.0
  │ │   └── next-tick@0.2.2
  │ ├── lodash@2.4.1
  │ └── mute-stream@0.0.4
  ├── js-string-escape@1.0.0
  ├─┬ leek@0.0.12
  │ ├── lodash@2.4.1
  │ └─┬ request@2.44.0
  │   ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
  │   ├─┬ bl@0.9.3
  │   │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.0.32
  │   │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
  │   │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │   │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
  │   │   └── string_decoder@0.10.31
  │   ├── caseless@0.6.0
  │   ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
  │   ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4
  │   │ ├── async@0.9.0
  │   │ ├─┬ combined-stream@0.0.5
  │   │ │ └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
  │   │ └── mime@1.2.11
  │   ├─┬ hawk@1.1.1
  │   │ ├── boom@0.4.2
  │   │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
  │   │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
  │   │ └── sntp@0.2.4
  │   ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
  │   │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
  │   │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
  │   │ └── ctype@0.5.2
  │   ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
  │   ├── mime-types@1.0.2
  │   ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
  │   ├── oauth-sign@0.4.0
  │   ├── qs@1.2.2
  │   ├── stringstream@0.0.4
  │   ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
  │   │ └── punycode@1.3.1
  │   └── tunnel-agent@0.4.0
  ├── lodash-node@2.4.1
  ├─┬ minimatch@1.0.0
  │ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
  │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
  ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0
  │ └── minimist@0.0.8
  ├─┬ morgan@1.3.2
  │ ├── basic-auth@1.0.0
  │ ├── depd@0.4.5
  │ └─┬ on-finished@2.1.0
  │   └── ee-first@1.0.5
  ├── ncp@0.6.0
  ├── nopt@3.0.1
  ├─┬ npm@2.1.2
  │ ├── abbrev@1.0.5
  │ ├── ansi@0.3.0
  │ ├── ansicolors@0.3.2
  │ ├── ansistyles@0.1.3
  │ ├── archy@0.0.2
  │ ├── async-some@1.0.1
  │ ├── block-stream@0.0.7
  │ ├── char-spinner@1.0.1
  │ ├── child-process-close@0.1.1
  │ ├── chmodr@0.1.0
  │ ├── chownr@0.0.1
  │ ├── cmd-shim@2.0.1
  │ ├─┬ columnify@1.2.1
  │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@1.0.0
  │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@0.2.1
  │ │ └─┬ wcwidth@1.0.0
  │ │   └─┬ defaults@1.0.0
  │ │     └── clone@0.1.18
  │ ├─┬ dezalgo@1.0.0
  │ │ └── asap@1.0.0
  │ ├── editor@0.1.0
  │ ├── fs-vacuum@1.2.1
  │ ├── fs-write-stream-atomic@1.0.2
  │ ├── fstream@1.0.2
  │ ├─┬ fstream-npm@1.0.0
  │ │ └── fstream-ignore@1.0.1
  │ ├── github-url-from-git@1.4.0
  │ ├── github-url-from-username-repo@1.0.2
  │ ├── glob@4.0.5
  │ ├── graceful-fs@3.0.2
  │ ├── inflight@1.0.1
  │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │ ├── ini@1.2.1
  │ ├─┬ init-package-json@1.1.0
  │ │ └── promzard@0.2.2
  │ ├── lockfile@1.0.0
  │ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
  │ ├─┬ minimatch@1.0.0
  │ │ └── sigmund@1.0.0
  │ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0
  │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
  │ ├── node-gyp@1.0.2
  │ ├── nopt@3.0.1
  │ ├── normalize-package-data@1.0.3
  │ ├── npm-cache-filename@1.0.1
  │ ├── npm-install-checks@1.0.4
  │ ├── npm-package-arg@2.1.2
  │ ├── npm-registry-client@3.2.2
  │ ├── npm-user-validate@0.1.0
  │ ├─┬ npmconf@2.1.0
  │ │ └─┬ config-chain@1.1.8
  │ │   └── proto-list@1.2.3
  │ ├── npmlog@0.1.1
  │ ├── once@1.3.0
  │ ├── opener@1.3.0
  │ ├── osenv@0.1.0
  │ ├── path-is-inside@1.0.1
  │ ├─┬ read@1.0.5
  │ │ └── mute-stream@0.0.4
  │ ├─┬ read-installed@3.1.3
  │ │ ├── debuglog@1.0.1
  │ │ ├── readdir-scoped-modules@1.0.0
  │ │ └── util-extend@1.0.1
  │ ├── read-package-json@1.2.7
  │ ├─┬ request@2.44.0
  │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
  │ │ ├─┬ bl@0.9.3
  │ │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.0.31
  │ │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
  │ │ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
  │ │ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.31
  │ │ ├── caseless@0.6.0
  │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
  │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4
  │ │ │ ├── async@0.9.0
  │ │ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@0.0.5
  │ │ │ │ └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
  │ │ │ └── mime@1.2.11
  │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.1.1
  │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
  │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
  │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
  │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
  │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
  │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
  │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
  │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
  │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
  │ │ ├── mime-types@1.0.2
  │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
  │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.4.0
  │ │ ├── qs@1.2.2
  │ │ ├── stringstream@0.0.4
  │ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
  │ │ │ └── punycode@1.3.1
  │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.0
  │ ├── retry@0.6.0
  │ ├── rimraf@2.2.8
  │ ├── semver@4.0.0
  │ ├─┬ sha@1.2.4
  │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.0.31
  │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
  │ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
  │ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.31
  │ ├── slide@1.1.6
  │ ├── sorted-object@1.0.0
  │ ├── tar@1.0.1
  │ ├── text-table@0.2.0
  │ ├── uid-number@0.0.5
  │ ├── which@1.0.5
  │ └── write-file-atomic@1.1.0
  ├── pleasant-progress@1.0.2
  ├── proxy-middleware@0.5.1
  ├─┬ quick-temp@0.1.2
  │ ├── mktemp@0.3.5
  │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
  ├─┬ readline2@0.1.0
  │ ├─┬ chalk@0.4.0
  │ │ ├── ansi-styles@1.0.0
  │ │ ├── has-color@0.1.7
  │ │ └── strip-ansi@0.1.1
  │ ├── lodash@2.4.1
  │ └── mute-stream@0.0.4
  ├── resolve@1.0.0
  ├── rimraf@2.2.8
  ├── rsvp@3.0.14
  ├── semver@3.0.1
  ├─┬ symlink-or-copy@1.0.0
  │ └── copy-dereference@1.0.0
  ├─┬ temp@0.8.1
  │ └── rimraf@2.2.8
  ├─┬ testem@0.6.19
  │ ├── async@0.2.10
  │ ├─┬ backbone@1.0.0
  │ │ └── underscore@1.7.0
  │ ├── charm@0.0.8
  │ ├── colors@0.6.2
  │ ├── commander@2.3.0
  │ ├── consolidate@0.8.0
  │ ├── did_it_work@0.0.6
  │ ├─┬ express@3.1.0
  │ │ ├── buffer-crc32@0.1.1
  │ │ ├── commander@0.6.1
  │ │ ├─┬ connect@2.7.2
  │ │ │ ├── bytes@0.1.0
  │ │ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11
  │ │ │ ├── pause@0.0.1
  │ │ │ └── qs@0.5.1
  │ │ ├── cookie@0.0.5
  │ │ ├── cookie-signature@0.0.1
  │ │ ├── debug@0.7.2
  │ │ ├── fresh@0.1.0
  │ │ ├── methods@0.0.1
  │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3
  │ │ ├── range-parser@0.0.4
  │ │ └─┬ send@0.1.0
  │ │   └── mime@1.2.6
  │ ├─┬ fileset@0.1.5
  │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.4.0
  │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
  │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
  │ ├─┬ fireworm@0.6.6
  │ │ ├─┬ is-type@0.0.1
  │ │ │ └── core-util-is@1.0.1
  │ │ ├── lodash@2.3.0
  │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
  │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
  │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
  │ ├─┬ glob@3.1.21
  │ │ ├── graceful-fs@1.2.3
  │ │ ├── inherits@1.0.0
  │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
  │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
  │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
  │ ├── growl@1.7.0
  │ ├─┬ http-proxy@0.10.4
  │ │ ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1
  │ │ │ ├── minimist@0.0.10
  │ │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
  │ │ ├── pkginfo@0.3.0
  │ │ └─┬ utile@0.2.1
  │ │   ├── deep-equal@0.2.1
  │ │   ├── i@0.3.2
  │ │   └── ncp@0.4.2
  │ ├─┬ js-yaml@2.1.3
  │ │ ├─┬ argparse@0.1.15
  │ │ │ ├── underscore@1.4.4
  │ │ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
  │ │ └── esprima@1.0.4
  │ ├── mustache@0.4.0
  │ ├─┬ npmlog@0.0.6
  │ │ └── ansi@0.2.1
  │ ├─┬ socket.io@0.9.17
  │ │ ├── base64id@0.1.0
  │ │ ├── policyfile@0.0.4
  │ │ ├── redis@0.7.3
  │ │ └─┬ socket.io-client@0.9.16
  │ │   ├─┬ active-x-obfuscator@0.0.1
  │ │   │ └── zeparser@0.0.5
  │ │   ├── uglify-js@1.2.5
  │ │   ├─┬ ws@0.4.32
  │ │   │ ├── commander@2.1.0
  │ │   │ ├── nan@1.0.0
  │ │   │ ├── options@0.0.5
  │ │   │ └── tinycolor@0.0.1
  │ │   └── xmlhttprequest@1.4.2
  │ ├── styled_string@0.0.1
  │ ├─┬ tap@0.4.13
  │ │ ├── buffer-equal@0.0.1
  │ │ ├── deep-equal@0.0.0
  │ │ ├─┬ difflet@0.2.6
  │ │ │ ├── charm@0.1.2
  │ │ │ ├── deep-is@0.1.3
  │ │ │ └── traverse@0.6.6
  │ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11
  │ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
  │ │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
  │ │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
  │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │ │ ├── nopt@2.2.1
  │ │ ├─┬ runforcover@0.0.2
  │ │ │ └─┬ bunker@0.1.2
  │ │ │   └─┬ burrito@0.2.12
  │ │ │     ├── traverse@0.5.2
  │ │ │     └── uglify-js@1.1.1
  │ │ ├── slide@1.1.6
  │ │ └── yamlish@0.0.6
  │ └── xml-escape@1.0.0
  ├── through@2.3.6
  ├─┬ tiny-lr@0.1.4
  │ ├─┬ body-parser@1.8.4
  │ │ ├── bytes@1.0.0
  │ │ ├── depd@0.4.5
  │ │ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.4
  │ │ ├── media-typer@0.3.0
  │ │ ├─┬ on-finished@2.1.0
  │ │ │ └── ee-first@1.0.5
  │ │ ├── raw-body@1.3.0
  │ │ └─┬ type-is@1.5.2
  │ │   └─┬ mime-types@2.0.2
  │ │     └── mime-db@1.1.0
  │ ├── debug@0.8.1
  │ ├─┬ faye-websocket@0.7.3
  │ │ └── websocket-driver@0.3.6
  │ ├── parseurl@1.3.0
  │ └── qs@2.2.4
  ├── walk-sync@0.1.3
  └─┬ yam@0.0.16
    ├─┬ findup@0.1.5
    │ ├── colors@0.6.2
    │ └── commander@2.1.0
    ├─┬ fs-extra@0.8.1
    │ ├── jsonfile@1.1.1
    │ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
    │ ├── ncp@0.4.2
    │ └── rimraf@2.2.8
    └── lodash@2.4.1

Comment: Do you need to open a new terminal session?

Comment: i am sorry i did not get what you are trying to point out

Answer (score 0):

The node_modules path was conflicting. `unset NODE_PATH` solved my problem as for nvm NODE_PATH is not required.

and then

```
source ~/.profile
```